# ¿Qué tipo de dato es mejor para almacenar un sólo carácter en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en la cual necesito almacenar una constante para identificar colores, es una letra, a manera de constante:

- `B`: blanco
- `R`: rojo
- `V`: verde
- `M`: morado
- `D`: dorado

Mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Cuál sería el mejor tipo de datos para almacenar mi letra identificadora, `CHAR(1), VARCHAR(1)`?

Estuve viendo una [tabla comparativa en la documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html), la cual me dejó confundido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según dicha tabla, un `CHAR(4)` requeriría mayor espacio de almacenamiento que un `VARCHAR(4)` ¿...?

No sé si un `CHAR(1)`  ocuparía también 4 bytes... y si un `VARCHAR(1)` ocuparía 1 byte.

O... ¿`ENUM` podría ser una mejor solución en este caso?

Mi tabla tiene estas características, extraídas del `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
...
ENGINE=MyISAM 
AUTO_INCREMENT=844 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci
```

Comment: Hola, ¿no seria mejor usar un numero en lugar de un carácter? en ese caso podría usar `tinyint(1)`.

Comment: @the-breaker sí, también podría ser, pero para perderme menos en el código pensé en un carácter, así. con la letra ya sé el color que es. De todos modos, me queda la duda, pues lo que dice la documentación me dejó algo confundido.

Comment: ya que mencionas que serían valores constantes que tal probar con char cuya longitud es de 0 a 255 caracteres?

Comment: char es tipo byte (0-255) varchar depende de la codificación , en utf8 puede llegar a ser 4 bytes por letra

Comment: ¿Como así @AlfredoPaz? Yo necesito solamente, por ahora, cinco identificadores.

Comment: revisaré la pregunta nuevamente creo no la comprendí

Comment: utf8mb4 es el utf8 real de mysql =P

Comment: ¿Recomendarías que ponga la codificación a `utf8mb4` @aloMalbarez?

Comment: utfmb4 sólo si vas a almacenar caracteres del utf8 extendido onda emojis o algun subset de caracteres en lenguajes asiaticos, para almacenar una sola letra usaria tinyint, dado que el valor es 0-255 y es facil convertir a ascii A=65 etc..

Comment: enum puede ser util para legibilidad, se guarda el index del array por asi decir : `enum 'blanco', 'rojo', 'verde'` luego haces `update table set color='blanco'` se guarda el 0

Comment: En la tabla sólo se almacenan datos, casi todos numéricos en realidad, es una tabla de control para hacer referencia a ids de otras tablas. Con la columna que quiero crear aquí yo quería un identificador descriptivo, que al verlo sepa de qué se trata.

Comment: ahi revisando la doc, el enum guarda el index empezando en 1 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Comment: según los ejemplos enum sería lo mas indicado, se guarda como numero pero se muestra y se selectea como string

Comment: Tal vez te convendria usar el tipo de datos `TINYINT` que almacena un solo byte, y usar el ascii del caracter que quieres almacenar para el codigo de color

Comment: Un `CHAR(4)` tiene fijos 4 bytes independientemente del contenido, un `VARCHAR(4)` dependerá de la longitud de lo que vayas a guardar, ¿Como se calcula? hay 1 byte fijo que sirve para definir la longitud del contenido, si guardas un blanco/NULL la longitud será 1 byte, si guardas 2 caracteres la longitud será 1 byte fijo más dos caracteres, etc. Por eso siempre se dice que los VARCHAR solo tienen eventual sentido con columnas de más de 3 bytes.

Comment: Algo más, un VARCHAR(1) ocupará 1 o 2 bytes (depende del contenido) un CHAR(1) ocupará siempre 1 byte. Resumiendo, sin duda te conviene CHAR(1).

Comment: ante la duda siempre un fidel http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/adfb1/2

Answer (score 0):

Jugando un poco con el fiddle me da la sensación de que un [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) es lo que estás buscando, en la tabla se almacena el índice (1 byte) y las operaciones se pueden hacer por índice o por palabra del enum

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (
      `id` int, 
      `nombre` varchar(10), 
      `color` ENUM('blanco', 'rojo', 'verde', 'morado', 'dorado')
    )
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `nombre`, `color`)
VALUES
    (1, 'numero uno', 'blanco'),
    (2, 'numero dos', 'verde'),
    (3, 'numero 3', 'blanco'),
    (4, 'numero 4', 'rojo'),
    (5, 'numero 5', 'blanco'),
    (6, 'numero 6', 'morado'),
    (7, 'numero 7', 'rojo'),
    (8, 'numero 8', 'dorado'),
    (9, 'numero 9', 'verde')
;
```

-- todos desordenados

```
select * from Table1;

id  nombre  color
1   numero uno  blanco
2   numero dos  verde
3   numero 3    blanco
4   numero 4    rojo
5   numero 5    blanco
6   numero 6    morado
7   numero 7    rojo
8   numero 8    dorado
9   numero 9    verde
```

-- filtrar por índice

```
select * from Table1 where color=1;

id  nombre  color
1   numero uno  blanco
3   numero 3    blanco
5   numero 5    blanco
```

-- filtrar por nombre

```
select * from Table1 where color='rojo';

id  nombre  color
4   numero 4    rojo
7   numero 7    rojo
```

-- ordenar por índice

```
select * from Table1 ORDER BY color;

id  nombre  color
1   numero uno  blanco
3   numero 3    blanco
5   numero 5    blanco
4   numero 4    rojo
7   numero 7    rojo
2   numero dos  verde
9   numero 9    verde
6   numero 6    morado
8   numero 8    dorado
```

-- ordenar por nombre

```
select * from Table1 ORDER BY CONCAT(color);

id  nombre  color
1   numero uno  blanco
3   numero 3    blanco
5   numero 5    blanco
8   numero 8    dorado
6   numero 6    morado
4   numero 4    rojo
7   numero 7    rojo
2   numero dos  verde
9   numero 9    verde
```

-- filtrar por índice mayor a (útil si es un nivel DEFCON)

```
select * from Table1 where color>3;

id  nombre  color
6   numero 6    morado
8   numero 8    dorado
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9f5fba/1

también considerar el rant en esta página
http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: y cual es la diferencia con varchar(1), que no requiere de otra tabla???

Comment: o con char, que siempre usa 1

Comment: claro la idea es que al hacer un select te aparezca el string y no el indice, no es tan dúctil como tener tabla aparte con sus keys pero eso dependerá de la aplicación y el modelo de datos

Comment: Usar un enumerado para solucionar un problema de las vistas, es un no no. Para saber que tipo de dato es, esta la vista. La db es solo para almacenar.

Comment: por eso digo que depende de la aplicación y el modelo de datos, supongo que para listas de mas de 10 cosas, o que cambien bastante ahí ya conviene un varchar indexado o un fk con tabla, hay que ver que lo hace mas adecuado a la situación sin caer en normalizar de mas o de menos o sobre optimizar algo. es cómodo q el select tire las cadenas sin join =P